# SharePoint spfx webpart Property 'value' does not exist. sub task errored

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I am trying to fetch data from SharePoint in **spfx web part with No javascript framework**. I am able to access the list and getting the response object but not able to access the value from the response object.

I am getting error as `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'IListItem[]`

below is my code:

```
private _GetListItemsNF(): void {
    var url = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('testList')/items?$select=Title,Id";
    this.context.spHttpClient.get(url, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
        .then((response: Response): Promise < IListItem[] > => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((response) => {
            alert(response.value);
        }, (error: any) => {
            alert(error);
        });
}
```

Refer below screenshot -

[image]

However when I debug the code I am able to access the value as `response.value` in debug console. Refer screenshot below for the same :

[image]

Can anybody please suggest me on this. Is there anything wrong with the code that I have written ?

Comment: Please share your list model where you have defined the list fields

Comment: @PriyaranjanKS I didn't understand what do you mean by list model. Can you please help me with your last comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a tslint error because there are no typings defined which say that `response` which is of type `IListItem[]` will have a property called `value`. The best way to solve this is to keep `response` of type `any` and then cast the `response.value` to `IListItem[]`. Here is your modified code:

```
private _GetListItemsNF(): void {
    var url = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('testList')/items?$select=Title,Id";
    this.context.spHttpClient.get(url, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((responseJSON) => {
        const listItems: IListItem[] = responseJSON.value;
        alert(listItems);
      }, (error: any) => {
        alert(error);
      });
  }
```

Notice I have also changed the type of first response object to `SPHttpResponse` which will also get rid of the warning. And I have changed the second response object to `responseJSON` to make it more explicit that it is a json object.

Answer (score 1):

1) `Response` is deprecated and replaced with `SPHttpClientResponse`.

So, modify your import statement as below:

`import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse, SPHttpClientConfiguration } 
from '@microsoft/sp-http';`

2) You need to modify the code as below:

```
.then((response: { value: IListItem[] }): void => {
        console.log(response.value);
```

Your full code block would be as below:

```
private _GetListItemsNF(): void {
    var url = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/
              getbytitle('testList')/items?$select=Title,Id";
    this.context.spHttpClient.get(url,SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IListItem[] }> => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((response: { value: IListItem[] }): void => {
        console.log(response.value);
      }, (error: any): void => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```